# How can I split a specific column to new columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, columnsorting

I want to split "rest" column to new columns by comma and drop "R=". And also add +1 to "joints" column. How can i do?

```
df
     joints           rest
          0  R=0,0,1,1,1,1
          3  R=0,0,1,1,1,1
         42  R=0,0,1,1,1,1
         45  R=0,0,1,1,1,1
```

I want to do like this:

```
joints U1 U2 U3 R1 R2 R3
1      0  0  1  1  1  1
4      0  0  1  1  1  1
43     0  0  1  1  1  1
46     0  0  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Are the values in the `rest` columns string values? You can find out by running `df.dtypes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more dynamic rename columns names is used function with lambda, for new columns is used [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` and assign back to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
f = lambda x: f'U{x+1}' if x < 3 else f'R{x-2}' 
df1 = (df.join(df.pop('rest').str.split('=')
                             .str[1]
                             .str.split(',', expand=True)
                             .rename(columns=f))
          .assign(joints = df['joints'] + 1))
print (df1)
   joints U1 U2 U3 R1 R2 R3
0       1  0  0  1  1  1  1
1       4  0  0  1  1  1  1
2      43  0  0  1  1  1  1
3      46  0  0  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: How can I change 0 to "No" and 1 to "Yes" ?

Comment: @Abdurrahman - Use `df = df.replace({'0':'No', '1':'Yes'})` after my code

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. Since there's no specified criteria for the column namings, I've just hardcoded in this case:

```
cols = ['U1', 'U2', 'U3', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3']
out = (df.rest.str.lstrip('R=')
              .str.split(',', expand=True)
              .rename(columns=dict(zip(range(len(cols)), cols)))
out['joints'] = df.joints.add(1)

  U1 U2 U3 R1 R2 R3  joints
0  0  0  1  1  1  1       1
1  0  0  1  1  1  1       4
2  0  0  1  1  1  1      43
3  0  0  1  1  1  1      46
```